# Raise adding or deleting action from child to add or delete elements in Parent StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I'm using C# and WPF to create an element with two buttons: (+) and (-)

This element is a child of a stackpanel in a main window.

I need to:

- Delete the element in which I've clicked on (-)
- Add another element in the stackpanel when I click on (+)

Does anyone can help me with a code, a website, a tutorial?

Thank you.

Here the element that I've create in a UserControl:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbx_configurationIsActive" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Button x:Name="btn_Edit" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonEditStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<Button x:Name="btn_Delete" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonPurgeStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<Label x:Name="Lbl_configName" Content="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Here an extract from the window were I'd like to add my element:

```
<ListBox Name="stk_configurationList">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationsList}"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You should use a `ListBox` for this instead of a `StackPanel`. It`s easier to add items to it and it is more flexible. If you want more help, you should post your code, how your view is implemented and what items you want to add.

Comment: @BionicCode, I've changed the StackPanel by ListBox, like you've told me to do. And I've posted some of my View to describe better the element that I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you. Are you using a view model? Where is the`ConfigurationsList` defined? Is every item having its own delete button?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a ViewModel. `ConfigurationList` is a property that I've defined in the ViewModel : `public List<ConfigurationItem> ConfigurationsList`, the `ConfigurationItem`is the item. And, yes, every item has its own delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ListBox` wrong. [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) derives from `ItemsControl`. Also you definitely should use a [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) instead of `List` in your scenario.

From your posted code, it seems you should read up some fundamental knowledge (I didn't check the quality of the linked content, but I generally recommend all Microsoft sources):

- [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)
- [Microsoft Docs: Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview)
- [Microsoft Docs: How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)
- [Microsoft Docs: Data binding overview in WPF/Binding to collections/How to implement collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#how-to-implement-collections)
- [The ListBox control](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/)

A simple example, how to add/remove items to/from a collection triggered by buttons:

**Configuration.cs**

```
class Configuration
{  
  public string TextValue { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**
(See [Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) for an implementation example of the `RelayCommand`)

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
  public ICommand DeletedItemCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteDeleteItem, CanExecuteDeleteItem);
  public ICommand AddItemCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteAddItem);

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Configurations = new ObservableCollection<Configuration>() 
    {
      new Configuration() {TextValue = "Initial Item"}
    };
  }

  private void CanExecuteDeleteItem(object commandParameter) => commandParameter is Configuration && this.Configurations.Any();

  private void ExecuteDeleteItem(object commandParameter) => this.Configurations.Remove(commandParameter as Configuration);

  private void ExecuteAddItem(object commandParameter) => this.Configurations.Add(new Configuration() {TextValue = "Some Text"});
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Item" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}">
      <ListBox.ItemTermplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Configuration}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock="{Binding TextValue}" />
            <Button Content="x" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTermplate>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```